# cordova zoom plugin in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to integrate cordova zoom plugin into my App. The plugin is here:[cordova-zoom-plugin](https://github.com/Biz4Solutions/cordova-zoomplugin)

Here is the [README file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX6QI.png).

I've tried to use the normal method to add the plugin but failed, the CLI command line is:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/Biz4Solutions/cordova-zoomplugin.git
```

The error message is:

```
dhcp-rhodes-2056:ionicApp aruhanliu$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/Biz4Solutions/cordova-zoomplugin
Error: Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/Biz4Solutions/cordova-zoomplugin via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm ERR! path /Users/aruhanliu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5a144746/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/aruhanliu/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-5a144746/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aruhanliu/.npm/_logs/2017-12-01T19_00_53_654Z-debug.log
```

Another question is that the plugin requires to bundle Zoom sdk and Dropbox sdk, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It seems that the cordova plugin interface requires a package.json while since it uses NPM behind the scenes. Maybe you will have to add this plugin manually to your project.